# Compiled Python binary reports wrong version

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

I tried to compile Python 2.7 from source.
 Here are my commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/my/local/dir --exec-prefix=/my/local/dir --enable-shared --with-pydebug
make
make install
```

And the output of `which python` is `/my/local/dir/bin/python`, which is correct.

But when I ran `python --version` I see `Python 2.7.3` instead of `Python 2.7.10`.

The system version of Python is 2.7.3. Could it be the system version of Python somehow links itself against the local, compiled version? Or am I doing something wrong?

Edit:

The output of `./my/local/dir/bin/python --version` is also `Python 2.7.3`

Edit 2:

Seems like if I get rid of the `--enable-shared` flag it will produce the correct version of Python, but I need that flag for my other software to work.

Comment: What happens if you run `/my/local/dir/bin/python --version`? If this case is correct, then your shell is simply caching the location of `python`, as o11c mentioned.

Comment: @Laogeodritt The output is still `Python 2.7.3`

Comment: On some systems, `which` is implemented as a program instead of a shell builtin and might not tell you what the shell will really run. Best to look at whatever command tells you what the shell really thinks. For `bash`, that command is `type`. Look at `help type` for more.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone `type python` still gives the same result

Comment: It'll tell you if the path is hashed (and `hash -r` would clear it). You might also want to try `type -a python` which will list *all* the pythons on your path, in order.

Comment: BTW, your edit is unclear: `./my/local/dir/bin/python` is not the same path as `/my/local/dir/bin/python` unless you're in the root directory for some reason. `--prefix=/my/local/dir` corresponds with the latter (absolute) path.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `--exec-prefix` option? I've never needed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So [this post](https://bugs.python.org/issue16883) is able to fix my issue. To quote the source:

> If you try to run a --enable-shared python executable from its build directory, you'll need to tell the dynamic loader where to find the shared library, i.e. the build directory itself. One way to do that is to use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.  Otherwise, the dynamic loader will search the standard paths, like /usr/local/lib/ and /usr/lib/ for a shared library with the proper name (like libpython2.7.so.1.0).  If there is an older Python already installed with that name and if the ABI hasn't changed too much, you may be lucky and it will load and run.

Comment: It seems that an `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` is required to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that shells cache the location of binaries instead of looking in `PATH` every time.

So, if you have run `python` previously in the same shell, it will still use the old version.

Use `hash -r` to fix this without starting a new shell.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. And I run `./my/local/dir/bin/python --version` and it still gives `Python 2.7.3`

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you need to change the `PYTHONHOME`environment variable so it uses the new version:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/my/local/dir/
```

> https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME

<sub>*If you want to make the change permanent consider adding it to your shell profile.</sub>