# "make" builds wrong python version

Tags: linux, python-2.7, build, compilation, mod-wsgi

**System** : SMEServer 8.1 (CentOS 5.10) 64bit, system python is 2.4.3

There is an alt python at /usr/local/bin/python2.7 (2.7.3) which was built some time ago.

**Goal** : build python2.7.10, mod_wsgi, django. First step is python 2.7.10 to replace the (older and broken) 2.7.3

**What happens:**

When i build the latest 2.7 python as **shared**, the wrong executable is built.

`cd /tmp && rm -vrf Python-2.7.10 && tar -xzvf Python-2.7.10.tgz && cd Python-2.7.10 && ./configure && make && ./python -V`

`2.7.10 <- as expected`

... but this wont work with mod_wsgi - we have to --enable-shared.

`cd /tmp && rm -vrf Python-2.7.10 && tar -xzvf Python-2.7.10.tgz && cd Python-2.7.10 && ./configure --enable-shared && make && ./python -V`

`2.7.3 <- Wrong version!`

I'm deleting the entire build directory each time to isolate things and ensure I'm not polluting the folder with each attempt. Somehow the (years old) install of 2.7.3 is being 'found' by configure but only when '--enable-shared' is on.

`cd /tmp && rm -vrf Python-2.7.10 && tar -xzvf Python-2.7.10.tgz && cd Python-2.7.10 && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ && make && ./python -V`

`2.7.10`

`cd /tmp && rm -vrf Python-2.7.10 && tar -xzvf Python-2.7.10.tgz && cd Python-2.7.10 && ./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local/ && make && ./python -V`

`2.7.3 <- ???`

Where do I look to find how make is finding old versions?

Comment: The solution for this issue, and good references, are discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362246/compiled-python-binary-has-wrong-version

Answer (score 1):

I'll document this here as the fix, also to hopefully get a comment from Graham as to why this might be needed;

Changing

`make`

to

`LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make`

was the answer, but i had to use this for building both python2.7.10 and mod_wsgi. Without using LD_RUN_PATH on mod_wsgi I still got the dreaded;

`[warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.10.
[warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.`

Comment: Perhaps read https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library and https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use and  https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Python_Patch_Level_Mismatch and https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Multiple_Python_Versions and

Comment: Thanks Graham. I'd read all those links, but just hadn't put it all together. I think the problem arose from installing 2.7.3 without --prefix which left things where 2.7.10 could find them. Thanks